# How insert xml namespace prefix C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I need to built a XML acording this [schema](http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd): http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd
I'm using Visual Studio XSD tool to made XSD --> C# Serializable Classes
When I serialize XML I get something like this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Comprobante xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" tipoDeComprobante="egreso" metodoDePago="" total="1081.18" LugarExpedicion="Veracruz, Veracruz" motivoDescuento="Deducciones nómina" fecha="2013-12-16T17:58:49.9881323-06:00" folio="1" version="3.2" serie="N" formaDePago="Pago una sóla exhibición" subTotal="1081.18" descuento="29.9" noCertificado="00001000000200056009" xmlns="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
      <Emisor nombre="SOLUCIONES ADMINISTRATIVAS VERACRUZANAS SA DE CV" rfc="SAV020911RR7">
        <DomicilioFiscal calle="AV. ALLENDE" noExterior="1409" colonia="CENTRO" localidad="VERACRUZ" referencia="CASI ESQUINA LERDO" municipio="VERACRUZ" estado="VERACRUZ" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="91700" />
        <ExpedidoEn calle="AV. ALLENDE" noExterior="1409" colonia="CENTRO" localidad="VERACRUZ" referencia="CASI ESQUINA LERDO" municipio="VERACRUZ" estado="VERACRUZ" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="91700" />
        <RegimenFiscal Regimen="REGIMEN GENERAL DE LEY PERSONAS MORALES" />
      </Emisor>
      <Receptor nombre="JOSE RAMIRO MURILLO FERNANDEZ" rfc="MUFR900501">
        <Domicilio pais="MEXICO" />
      </Receptor>
<!-- ... ... ... -->
    </Comprobante>
```

But I need to get something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3/cfdv3.xsd" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" tipoDeComprobante="egreso" metodoDePago="" total="1081.18" LugarExpedicion="Veracruz, Veracruz" motivoDescuento="Deducciones nómina" fecha="2013-12-16T17:58:49.9881323-06:00" folio="1" version="3.2" serie="N" formaDePago="Pago una sóla exhibición" subTotal="1081.18" descuento="29.9" noCertificado="00001000000200056009" >
      <cfdi:Emisor nombre="SOLUCIONES ADMINISTRATIVAS VERACRUZANAS SA DE CV" rfc="SAV020911RR7">
        <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="AV. ALLENDE" noExterior="1409" colonia="CENTRO" localidad="VERACRUZ" referencia="CASI ESQUINA LERDO" municipio="VERACRUZ" estado="VERACRUZ" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="91700" />
        <cfdi:ExpedidoEn calle="AV. ALLENDE" noExterior="1409" colonia="CENTRO" localidad="VERACRUZ" referencia="CASI ESQUINA LERDO" municipio="VERACRUZ" estado="VERACRUZ" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="91700" />
        <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="REGIMEN GENERAL DE LEY PERSONAS MORALES" />
      </cfdi:Emisor>
      <cfdi:Receptor nombre="JOSE RAMIRO MURILLO FERNANDEZ" rfc="MUFR900501">
        <cfdi:Domicilio pais="MEXICO" />
      </cfdi:Receptor>
<!-- ... ... ... -->
    </cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Why XSD tool doesn't include "

```
xsd.exe cdf32.xsd /c /order
```

How can I include this prefix on XML?